# Android : Cant get json printed on https site

Tags: android, json, http

This script works on normal servers but when i tried in https server its not returning the json data that i created

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

        HttpPost httpPost = null;

        try {
            httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxxxxx.xx");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try{

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();

            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jObj;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add SSL certificate.

```
public DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
```

copy this function and create DefaultHttpClient object as.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();
```

Rest of the code remains same...

Below is my MySSLSocketFactory class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding the host name, port number and "https" in the request.

```
 HttpPost httpPost = null;
 String HOST = "sample.com"; 
 int port = 80;
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
 HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(HOST, portnumber, "https");
    try {
        httpPost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxxxxx.xx");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost,Port,localContext);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Im having problems in : 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost,Port,localContext);